# Regarding priority of the increment operators

Tags: c, operators

From what I know

```
int i = 10;
int j = 5;
j += ++i; //j = 16, i = 11 (first i increments and then adds to j)
```

And

```
int i = 10;
int j = 5;
j += i++; //j = 15, i = 11 (first i adds to j and then increments)
```

In [C in a nutshell](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/c-in-a/0596006977/ch05.html) in the Table 5-4 (Operator precedence and associativity) it says the postfix operator ++ has priority over the unary operator ++, which I don't understand, as the opposite is what I wrote previously.

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLpB9.png)

Why's that?

Comment: The first snippet says to first increment i and then use it; the second says to first use i and then incfrement it.

Comment: Exactly. That is what I wrote, because that's what I knew. But in the website it seems to be the opposite.

Comment: Since ++ pre and ++ post are not used in the same expression, there is no precedence of these operators to take into account.

Comment: That's a good point! If it was able though, which one would have precedence? surely prefix? (which is not what's in the table)

Comment: I prefer this table: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Well... in theory you could do `++*p++` and it's even well-defined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator precedence/associativity only states the order in which C code should be *parsed*. This has nothing to do with how the code is to be executed<sup>1)</sup>.

Meaning that if you have something like `*p++` it is equivalent to `*(p++)`, because postfix ++ takes precedence over unary `*`. But when that code is later executed, the memory location `*p` will get derefenced first, and the address of `p` incremented by 1 item later.

This is in turn because postfix ++ follows a rule which says that "the value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value of the operand".

---

<sup>1)</sup> Think of a math equation such as: `a * b + c * d` - operator precedence in math and C forces you to calculate this as `(a * b) + (c * d)` but it doesn't tell you anything about whether you should calculate `a * b` before or after `c * d`.

Comment: The C standard does not say that `*(p++)` dereferences `p` before incrementing it. It says the value used in the dereference is the value before the increment. The compiler may fetch that value (which effects “the value computation of the result”), increment `p` (sequenced after the value computation), and dereference the previously fetched value (not sequenced relative to the update of `p`). And with `volatile` types, the order would be observable.